# Distinguish between NewMessage and MessageEdited in Telethon?

Tags: python, telethon

I have a Python (3.9) class which is monitoring message edits and new messageas in channels. Is there any way to know in the code whether the message was edited or if it's a new message? According to the documentation, edited messages should be treated like new messages.

I tried the following code without success:

```
class TelegramBot:

    # --------------------------------
    # Initialization
    # --------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        client.add_event_handler(
            self.message_listener,
            events.NewMessage(
                chats=get_chat_ids(
                    "X",
                    "Y",
                    "Z",
                )
            ),
        )
    # Register the event handler for edited messages
    client.add_event_handler(
        self.message_listener,
        events.MessageEdited(chats=get_chat_ids("X", "Y")),
    )


    async def message_listener(self, event):
        message = event.message.message
        message_id = event.message.id  # Get the ID of the triggering message

        if event.chat_id in get_chat_ids("X", "Y"):
            if isinstance(event, events.NewMessage):
                ...
            elif isinstance(event, events.MessageEdited):
                ...
```

It also seems an edited message triggers both event types, meaning one message executes my code twice.

Using print for the event type shows the same:

`{type(event).__name__}`

yields `Event`

Answer (score 0):

Since the base class for `events.MessageEdited` is `events.NewMessage`, check if it's an instance of `events.MessageEdited`, if it's not then it's an instance of `events.NewMessage`.

```python
if isinstance(event, events.MessageEdited):
    # it's an edited message
else:
    # it's a new message
```

Comment: Unfortunately not working, always enters the "else", regardless of whether it's an edited message or new message.

Comment: That's interesting, perhaps it's a bug with `telethon`. Do you mind editing your question to include the code for `message_listener`.

Comment: Oh `event` is just a proxy object over the message, that's why `isinstance` is not working and `type(event).__name__` yields `Event`.

Comment: I edited the code to include the `message_listener`. What does it mean it's a proxy object? Is there another solution then?

Comment: @Qliver thank you for adding `message_listener` to your question. A proxy object follows the [proxy design pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/proxy). Telethon's [`NewMessage` documentation](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/quick-references/events-reference.html#newmessage) states *"Remember, this event is just a proxy over the message..."*. I believe they're using a *proxy* due to the code being async, similar to the use of `Promise` in JavaScript async code.

Comment: @Qliver I'm working on figuring out another/correct solution and I'll let you know when and if I find one.